# Angular Authentication

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, authentication, routes

The problem is on every $routeChangeStart if user is not found it still directs me to pages if I just type the url.

Now I have rewrite the rules on the server.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]
```

And here is the app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($httpProvider){


    // attach our Auth interceptor to the http requests
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');


});


app.run(['$rootScope','$scope','Auth', '$location', function($rootScope, $scope, Auth, $location){
     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event){
        $scope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        console.log(Auth.isLoggedIn());

        Auth.getUser().then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.user = response;
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });

    });
}]);
```

And here is mine angular auth factory

```
app.factory('AuthToken', function($window){

    var authTokenFactory = {};

    authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token){
        if(token){
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        }else{
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
    };

    authTokenFactory.getToken = function(){
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    return authTokenFactory;
});


app.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken, Passingtoken){

    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.login = function(email, password){
        var data = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        };

        return $http.post('/loginForm.php', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function(response){
           // console.log(response);
            AuthToken.setToken(response.data);
            return response;
        }).catch(function(e){
            console.log(e);
            return $q.reject(e.data);
        });
    };


    authFactory.logout = function(){
        AuthToken.setToken();
    };

    authFactory.isLoggedIn = function(){
        if(AuthToken.getToken()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    };

    authFactory.getUser = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        if(AuthToken.getToken()){
            var userdata = JSON.parse(Passingtoken.getUserData());
            userdata = userdata[0].data;
            console.log(userdata);

            /**
             * get the token. Might make this a service that just gets me this token when needed.
             */
            $http.post('/decode.php', {
                userdata
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data.rows[0]);
                //$scope.username = response.data.rows[0].fullname;
                defer.resolve(response.data.rows[0]);
            }, function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
        }else{
            return $q.reject({
                message: 'User not found'
            });
        }
        return defer.promise;
    };


    return authFactory;
});


app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken){

    var interceptorFactory = {};

    interceptorFactory.request = function(config){
        // grab a token
        var token = AuthToken.getToken();
        // if token is there added to header
        if(token){
            config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
        }

        return config;
    };

    interceptorFactory.responseError = function (response) {

        if (response.status == 403){   
            AuthToken.setToken();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);

    };


    return interceptorFactory;
});
```

And here is maincontroller where I am checking for route change

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Passingtoken', '$http','$window', 'Auth', '$location', '$rootScope', function($scope, Passingtoken, $http, $window, Auth, $location, $rootScope){

    // check for loggin in
    $scope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

    // rootscope
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event){
        $scope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        console.log(Auth.isLoggedIn());

        Auth.getUser().then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.user = response;
        }).catch(function(error){

            console.log(error);
        });

    });


     $scope.logged = function(){
        if($scope.loginData.email !== '' && $scope.loginData.password !== ''){
            Auth.login($scope.loginData.email, $scope.loginData.password).then(function(response){
                //console.log(response);
                if(response.data !== 'failed'){
                    Passingtoken.addData(response);
                    $location.path("/home");
                    //$window.location.reload();
                }else{

                }
            }, function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    };



    /**
     * Logout function
     */
    $scope.logout = function(){
        Auth.logout();

        $scope.username = "";
        $location.path("/");
    }

}]);
```

In $rootscope.on I am checking if user has the token and if user does then route can change (I am using jwt), but if I go through url then it will take me anywhere even if I don't have the token. In my maincontroller I try to add $location.path('/') in .catch() then on every route change it will take me to that path even if I am not logged in and try to click on login it will redirect me to that path and that make sense. I am just lost on how to make sure a user cannot get in through the url and angular should just check on every request. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should move your `$on('$routeChangeStart')` call to your main application module's `run` section

Comment: @Phil I am not using run section at all.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should

Comment: @Phil I added a run method in my app.js as you see in the above example but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

move this portion of code into your application's run block.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event){
        $scope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        console.log(Auth.isLoggedIn());

        Auth.getUser().then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.user = response;
        }).catch(function(error){

            console.log(error);
        });

    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I added .run module in my app.js but I am still able to access the pages if I go through url